# Things to keep in mind when working on new CMS

Tags: web-applications, content-management-system

I would like to know that what should a developer should keep in mind when he is having a web application to extend some of functionalities or to fix a list of bugs developed in a CMS which is totally new for him? How should start the work? What are the steps to work with that? And especially when the programming experience is not too much and having a tight deadline not allowing to completely learn that particular CMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best suggestion I can give you is to seek help:

- from the community around a CMS. There are a lot of very active (open source) communities around popular CMS's. Use them. You can always introduce yourself (on a forum/mailinglist) and explain what you're trying to achieve and pick up on suggestions. Especially when you're extending some functionality/plugin it's best to ask around. Maybe others want the same thing and help you or you'll get pointers how to do it, so you don't end up with a forked un-upgradable CMS.
- when you don't have a lot of programming experience, seek someone/a party that has. There's help for almost every budget. Really, it can save you a lot of time, effort and money to ask a professional.

Hope this helps.